# min and max in legacy C++

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm, max, min

I am trying to compile some older C++ code (probably from around 2001-2002) on a Debian GNU/Linux stable system.  When compiling, I get the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:66:0,
                 from ../FooMath/FooBar.h:23,
                 from FooBar.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::max_size() const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_bvector.h:685:2: error: ‘max’ is not a member of ‘__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<long int>’
```

Hunting down the problem, I came across this piece of code in one of our own header files, which I assume is related to this problem:

```
#if defined(IRIX) | linux
signed  max(signed a, signed b);
long    max(long a, long b);
double  max(double a, double b);
float   max(float a, float b);
signed  min(signed a, signed b);
long    min(long a, long b);
double  min(double a, double b);
#define  __min min
#define  __max max
float   min(float a, float b);
#endif
```

and at lots of other places, I see calls to a `__max()` function with two arguments.

My educated guess is that I can replace all these calls to `__max()` with calls to `std::max()` and that I should include the `<algorithm>` header.

My two questions are:

1. Is my educated guess correct?

   I assume the extra declarations and defines of min and max are some historical leftover.  Does anyone know the history of it?  Why was this code ever needed?

Comment: From the error message, `max` seems related to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max not the one from algorithm.

Comment: You should post an MCVE. The likeliest explanation is that there is a bug in your code.

Comment: I hope you don't edit system header.

Comment: Identifiers starting with double underscores are reserved to the implementation. Replace all your double underscore stuff in your code with a single underscore or something else.

Comment: Are you including your own headerfile before standard library header files anywhere in your code?

Comment: Replacing `#define __max max` by `#define  __max(a, b) max(a, b)` may do the job.

Answer (score 0):

At the line 685 in `bits/stl_bvector.h` you have :

```
    __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<difference_type>::__max
```

Your ugly macro is replacing `__max` by `max`, hence the error.

You can effectively replace all your `__max` in your code by `std::max`, but just to be sure not to dismantle everything, you could first rename `__max` by `__my__max`, just to be sure (in your macro too). That way you will keep using the self-defined min/max functions.

---

Another solution would be to `undef` your macro before including stl headers and reenabling it after.

Comment: The thing is, we don't know if the ugly macro is in a standard library implementation file. There simply isn't enough information in the question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the "a certain header file" is not that clear.

Comment: "a certain header file" is actually one of our own headers files, not a system header file.  I changed that in the question, tnx.